# Redrawing a google map to bring to view a hidden moving marker

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a marker that moves inside a google map like http://jsfiddle.net/t43kaeyr/1/

However,there are times when the marker is not visible within the confines of the map canvas and i wonder how i can redraw the map to make visible the moving marker.

I have looked posts from the past but i cant seem to get it right.This is the css of the map canvas

```
#map_canvas {
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

**code snippet (from linked fiddle):**

```js
var map, marker;
var startPos = [42.42679066670903, -83.29210638999939];
var speed = 50; // km/h

var delay = 100;
// If you set the delay below 1000ms and you go to another tab,
// the setTimeout function will wait to be the active tab again
// before running the code.
// See documentation :
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Inactive_tabs

function animateMarker(marker, coords, km_h) {
  var target = 0;
  var km_h = km_h || 50;
  coords.push([startPos[0], startPos[1]]);

  function goToPoint() {
    var lat = marker.position.lat();
    var lng = marker.position.lng();
    var step = (km_h * 1000 * delay) / 3600000; // in meters

    var dest = new google.maps.LatLng(
      coords[target][0], coords[target][1]);

    var distance =
      google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(
        dest, marker.position); // in meters

    var numStep = distance / step;
    var i = 0;
    var deltaLat = (coords[target][0] - lat) / numStep;
    var deltaLng = (coords[target][1] - lng) / numStep;

    function moveMarker() {
      lat += deltaLat;
      lng += deltaLng;
      i += step;

      if (i < distance) {
        marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
        setTimeout(moveMarker, delay);
      } else {
        marker.setPosition(dest);
        target++;
        if (target == coords.length) {
          target = 0;
        }

        setTimeout(goToPoint, delay);
      }
    }
    moveMarker();
  }
  goToPoint();
}

function initialize() {
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 16,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(42.425175091823974, -83.2943058013916),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(startPos[0], startPos[1]),
    map: map
  });

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    animateMarker(marker, [
      // The coordinates of each point you want the marker to go to.
      // You don't need to specify the starting position again.
      [42.42666395645802, -83.29694509506226],
      [42.42300508749226, -83.29679489135742],
      [42.42304468678425, -83.29434871673584],
      [42.424882066428424, -83.2944130897522],
      [42.42495334300206, -83.29203128814697]
    ], speed);
  });
}

initialize();
```

```css
#map_canvas {
  width: 600px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: I believe you are on the right track, you need to redraw the map each time the marker moves outside the maps view.  Usually the easiest way to handle this is by creating a draw map function, and calling that function whenever a specific action takes place (ie. the marker moving outside of the lat/long view).  This should work, because the map should redraw with all markers in view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest solution is to center the map on the moving marker:

```
function moveMarker() {
    lat += deltaLat;
    lng += deltaLng;
    i += step;

    if (i < distance) {
            marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            setTimeout(moveMarker, delay);
        } else {
            marker.setPosition(dest);
            map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            target++;
            if (target == coords.length) {
                target = 0;
        }

        setTimeout(goToPoint, delay);
    }
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/t43kaeyr/2/)

Another option would be if you know the marker is reasonably close to the area covered by your map, you could zoom out the map until it is visible.

```
function moveMarker() {
    lat += deltaLat;
    lng += deltaLng;
    i += step;

    if (i < distance) {
        marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
        if (!map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())) {
            // marker out of view, zoom out 
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
        }
        setTimeout(moveMarker, delay);
    } else {
        marker.setPosition(dest);
        if (!map.getBounds().contains(marker.getPosition())) {
            // marker out of view, zoom out 
            map.setZoom(map.getZoom() - 1);
        }
        target++;
        if (target == coords.length) {
            target = 0;
        }

        setTimeout(goToPoint, delay);
    }
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/t43kaeyr/3/)